# Like operator in VB.NET (sometimes) better and easier than regexes?

Tags: regex, vb.net, pattern-matching

I really enjoy using **Like operator** of VB.NET. It suffices for the majority of my uses, and I am sure this is true for the 'average' developer.

One of the main resason I avoid regexes is that the syntax is complicated and it is hard to see at first glance what is happening. The Like operator uses fool-proof syntax.

Is it just me, or do other people have similar views? On the same note, is there such than as a 'simplified' regex notation.

Like operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278293/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-the-vb-net-like-operator-vs-a-regex) ... possibly a duplicate.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are not considered constructive in Stack Exchange sites. Please avoid such questions and limit yourself to actual programming issues when asking on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use whatever your company's standards dictate or, if that's not applicable, whatever your personal standards dictate.

Some people are intimately familiar with Regular Expressions and would prefer the complete syntax.  Others are not and may be more comfortable with the `Like` operator (in my environment, a lot of folks cross from the T-SQL world to .NET so the `Like` operator is very familiar).

Additionally, as per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx), the `Like` operator can be overloaded such that you can utilize it for comparison on your own types, as opposed to just `strings`.